# Is upgrading my town hall without upgrading defenses a bad idea?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If a person upgrades their town hall without upgrading their defenses at the same rate, does that higher town hall change the ranking in the war and in a way hurt the clan because someone was in a hurry to get a higher town hall?

Answer (score 5):

According to Supercell:

> Strength is based on each member’s attacking power (troops, army camp capacity, spells and heroes) and defensive strength (defense buildings, walls, traps and heroes). Different layouts and base designs do not affect strength. The only way a member’s strength can be changed is if they upgrade their troops, defenses, spells, etc.

Another quote:

> Once a match is found, players are sorted on the map from strongest to weakest, in terms of defence power of their base, i.e., defense levels, hero levels, traps, etc.
>   **We do not take TH levels into account.** Instead, we only use overall strength of all defence elements in player’s village. For example, a TH8 with higher level defenses than a TH9 will be ranked higher than the TH9 in the war map.
>   XP has no bearing on the ranking of your war base on the war map

[Source](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/237478-Clan-Wars-FEEDBACK-here)

Comment: Of course, there's plenty of other reasons as to why upgrading your town hall prematurely is a terrible idea.

Comment: Fair enough, but that wasn't the question.  The question simply focus' on whether it's bad for the war or not.

Answer (score 0):

Rushed TH are not only a liability to yourself but also your clan And a delightful find whilst raiding and warring for everyone else

How is strength calculated in clan wars

Strength is based on each member’s attacking power (troops, army camp capacity, spells and heroes) and defensive strength (defense buildings, walls, traps and heroes).

lower level defenses and troops are a recipe for disaster